# Apigee shell delete all entities in a collection?

Tags: apigee

Is it possible to delete all entities in a collection using the shell? I need to refresh names of a very large collection and have a script that will accomplish this but I do need to delete them all first. Failing that, can I delete an app and start over?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apigee Usergrid: Mass delete option missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205880/apigee-usergrid-mass-delete-option-missing)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete all entities in a collection in one go, but you can select all entities on a page in the Admin Console and delete the selected entities.  That is certainly faster than doing it individually, but for a really large collection, this may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way currently:

DELETE /yourcollectionname?select * where created > 0&limit=100

You can do the equivalent of this in the Data Explorer.  Just fill out the query and the limit boxes.

Or, run this command via curl

We will have a better solution in the near future.

Comment: So I couldn't get this to work and resorted to creating a new App. I tried in the data explorer and just hangs. Is there a better way of achieving a delete yet?